# Issue updating a contact

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a function for google sheets that will update a contact

The function so far gets the target contact but when I try to make an update nothing happens.
I look up under contacts and also `ContactsApp.getContacts()` reflects the data was unchanged when I run it.

```
function editContact() {
    //get highlighted (active) cell data and first cell in its row(id)
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var aCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var id = grabId(aCell)

    var strArray = [];
    //fetch contact
    var contact = ContactsApp.getContactById(id);//works
    contact.setFamilyName('Doe-Smith');//does NOT work
    var contactName = contact.getFullName();//grabs old unaffected name
    strArray.push("contact", contactName);

    var title = "Target cell info"
    var str = stringMaker(strArray)

    showOutputBox(str, title);
}
```

I get no indication of error at all.
Your assistance in this matter is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to missleading [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#setFullName(String)), where it states

> `getFullName()` Gets the full name (given name and last name) of the
>   contact as a string.

In reality, `FullName` as it is refers to the display name in Google Contacts.

Try the following code:

```
  Logger.log('given: '+contact.getGivenName());
  Logger.log('last: '+contact.getFamilyName());
  Logger.log('family: '+contact.getFullName());
  contact.setGivenName('Joe');
  contact.setFamilyName('Doe-Smith');
  contact.setFullName('Testname');
  Logger.log('given: '+contact.getGivenName());
  Logger.log('last: '+contact.getFamilyName());
  Logger.log('family: '+contact.getFullName());
```

You will see that all three parameters have been changed, but `FullName` is an independent parameter, rather than a combination of the given and family name.

So, as a workaround, for the moment you will need to set and get given and family name separately.

Comment: I've filed a report with google hopefullly it'll be addressed. .. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140817923

Comment: thank you!
this is indeed the solution I was after.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Seems the method works after all but does not reflect in the contacts.google.com until I make an edit manually to affected contact.

90% sure they will prove I am a dummie but 10% sure I'm actually right and this is indeed a bug.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140817923